# Pre-install debian on a drive by plugging it into a computer other than the one it is intended for

Tags: debian, software-installation, hard-disk

I have an APU2 machine which outputs everything via its serial console. Is it possible to plug its mSATA drive into my windows laptop, install Debian using a live CD and then plug it back into APU2?

Answer (score 0):

The installer is intended to install to the hardware where it is running on. But if you have a running Linux-system, you can use [debootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/de/Debootstrap) to install a minimal system to the drive.
If you have a serial adapter you can do the installation directly as described [here](https://blog.dbrgn.ch/2019/10/5/booting-installing-debian-on-apu2/).

Comment: My serial adapter is on the way but I was wondering if this was indeed possible.